# Horizontal Coloured Bar

Tags: android

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/HeadIm1"
android:background="@drawable/menu"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="JEWELLERY DETAILS"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
android:textSize="14dp" />
```

I want a coloured Horixontal Bar saying Jewellery Details
so I have written this code but the problem is its width is not filling the parent 
its leaving some padding at both the sides Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default `RelativeLayout` generated in Eclipse when you create a new Android application, it will include the following padding:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Remove these lines.

Comment: Thanks, Done , One more thing I am using a text view there can u suggest what exactly should i use please see the Image link given below I am talking about the horizontal golden coloured bar
link: http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-1-s-307x512.jpg